# Таблица с редактированием на AngularJS + Bootstrap 3 - как организовать?

Tags: bootstrap, angularjs

Стоит задача получить данные с сервера из БД - т.е. набор записей. И отобразить их на сайте в виде таблицы с возможностью добавления новой записи, редактирования какой-то конкретной записи, и удаления этой записи. Редактирование может происходить либо непосредственно в ячейках таблицы, либо на другой странице/в модальном окне. После нажатия на кнопу удалить должно выдаваться диалоговое окно. После подтверждения запись должна удаляться и визуально из таблицы, и отправляться запрос на сервер. Причем по идее визуально строка должна удаляться только после успешного удаления на сервере из базы, иначе может возникнуть нестыковка. 
При редактировании непосредственно в таблице нашел [вот такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/93/) с [Angular-xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/)

Если в ячейках редактирование невозможно (например, форма редактирования содержит дополнительные поля), то по идее должно открываться некое модальное окно с формой

На сайте используется Bootstrap.Также [Bootstrap UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Предположим, я получаю в контроллере данные в виде `JSON`. Приходит идея через `ng-repeat` вывести в виде таблицы все записи, прикрутить кнопки, по нажатию одной переходить на страницу с формой редактирования, по нажатию другой - выдавать диалоговое окно и посылать DELETE запрос с id записи на сервер, но ведь есть более удобные способы? Как лучше организовать таблицу?
Может, есть какие-то плагины/библиотеки?

В целом, тривиальная задача отображения и редактирования.
Меня интересует именно не основы теории, а реализация непосредственно с AngularJS, не хотелось бы изобретать велосипед и писать всю реализацию вручную с нуля.

Обновление: пока нашел [такой вариант](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/), изучаю

Comment: То, что вы ищите - одна из самых распространенных задач веб-программирования. Почитайте про CRUD (Create-Read-Update-Delete)

Comment: @php5engineer спасибо за подсказку, но не хотелось бы писать всю реализацию вручную, возможно есть уже готовые решения? Пока нашел вот такой вариант http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

Comment: А после того, как прочитаете то, что посоветовал Инженер, то плагины/библиотеки стоит ПОИСКАТЬ... (https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=AngularJS+plugin+table+edit)

Comment: @cyadvert спасибо, но поиск в гугле пока ничего подходящего не выдал, поэтому пост и создан. Пока нашелся только http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/ изучаю его

Comment: :) ну так Гугл именно эту smart-table первую и выдает... так что мы оба пришли к одному и тому же :)

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы ищите - одна из самых распространенных задач веб-программирования. Называется CRUD (Create-Read-Update-Delete). Сейчас в веб-фреймворках уже вместо `Hello World` часто делают имплементацию CRUD.
Если поискать готовый [CRUD для фреймворков, указанных в заголовке](https://www.google.ru/search?q=angular%20bootstrap%20crud), на первых позициях в гугле находится [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/ggnZZm/)

Comment: спасибо за подсказку! Пример по ссылке Plunker  - у меня ничего не происходит при попытке добавления новой записи.